# Filter Regular Expression per column and row. Combined

Tags: python, databricks

i'm figuring out how to solve this problem.

first row contains: NUMBER: INC00012, AdditionalComment: NOT Yet Requested

Second row contains: NUMBER: INC0000001, AdditionalComment: w Yet Requested
DF_FILE_PATH = direction to the csv. files which contains these rows.

```
WrongData_REG_EXP =(DF_FILE_PATH
     .filter(DF_FILE_PATH.Number.rlike('^((?!INC([0-9]){7}).)*$'))
     .filter(DF_FILE_PATH.AdditionalComments.rlike('^((?!Not Yet Requested).)*$'))
     )
     display (WrongData_REG_EXP)
```

it's displaying the incorrect variable when i load only one filter. but when I add a new filter. It doesn't display anything. This is because there is no row which has those 2 regular expressions. 
but another row has the second filter and the first row has the first filter.

How can I display them both?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this was a sql query in Databricks with python.

```
query = '''
    ---- Get Corrupt records
    select * from bi4it_da.{0}_{1}_{2}_full_no_corrupt_NEW
    where number in
    (
    SELECT {0}_{1}_{2}_Full_No_Corrupt_NEW.number FROM BI4IT_DA.{0}_{1}_{2}_Full_No_Corrupt_NEW
    MINUS
    SELECT {0}_{1}_{2}_Full_Data_Set.number FROM BI4IT_DA.{0}_{1}_{2}_Full_Data_Set
    )
    '''.format(PROCESS_TYPE, SOURCE_SYSTEM, SOURCE_FILE_NAME)
display(spark.sql(query))
```

Full data set minus the good records wrong records remain.